# can not get my individuals from my ontology using search method in owlready python

Tags: python, owl, ontology, owlready

I have an ontology : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/amiraelsayed/lumiere/master/lumiere3.owl

I want to get all lessons for specific class called CS-Java

I have tried to use owlready search method and add to it filtration with lesson name and object properties but always give 0 while it should retrieve about 19 item

This is my individual

```
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#CS-Java">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Course"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Arrays"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Do_..._While"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Final"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#For_Loops"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Getting_User_Input"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Hello_World_Program"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#If_conditions"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Introduction_and_Installation"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Method_Parameters"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Methods"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Multi-Dimensional_Arrays"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Static"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#String_Builder_and_String_Formatting"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Switch"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Using_Variables"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#What_Java_Is_and_How_It_Works"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#While_Loops"/>
        <contains rdf:resource="http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#Strings:_Working_With_Text"/>
        <Code rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">CS102</Code>
        <Description rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Literal">This course of study builds on the skills gained by students in Java Fundamentals or Java Foundations to help advance Java programming skills. Students will design object-oriented applications with Java and will create Java programs using hands-on, engaging activities.</Description>
        <Name rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Introduction to Java Programming Language</Name>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

this is the class and it is contain list of lesson individuals

`onto.search(part_of="*")` it brings all lessons in all courses and when I used `onto.search(part_of="CS-Java")` it return 0 while I need it to return only lessons in this course

Comment: what do you mean by "owlready search method" ? can you show your code ?

Comment: @mgc please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your search returns 0 result because the `search` method can only be used to perform [Full Text Search](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/annotations.html#full-text-search-fts) on the content of the annotations.

It seems that what you need is to perform a query against the knowledge contained in your ontology, so maybe using SPARQL could be an idea ?

Owlready offers a way to [perform SPARQL queries on an ontology](https://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/world.html#working-with-rdflib-for-performing-sparql-queries), so you could express something like "Select all the things that CS-Java contains" :

```
# convert the ontology to a RDFLib graph
graph = onto.world.as_rdflib_graph()

# perform the query
result = list(graph.query_owlready("""
prefix : <http://www.smacrs.com/lumiere.owl#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?c WHERE {
  :CS-Java :contains ?c .
}"""))
```

The other way the go could simply be to read the content of the `contains` property on your `CS-Java` class :

```
onto['CS-Java'].contains
```

Both methods returns a list a Owlready2 objects (18 in your example case).